# Add a spinner to Add to Basket and Place Order buttons in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, woocommerce

I am using an upload option on products and want to show a spinner on both the Add to Basket button and Place Order button on the final checkout page.
The code below is for a spinner but I am unsure which class to use or how to trigger this (PHP or jQuery)

Here is the example theme:

https://demo.themeisle.com/hestia/product/mens-classic-regular-fit-jean/

```
/* 
* Custom AJAX spinner on WooCommerce checkout 
* The class used to load the overlay is .blockUI .blockOverlay
* The class used to load the spinner is .woocommerce .loader:before
*
*/
.woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay:before,.woocommerce .loader:before {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -.5em;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  animation: none;
  background: url('https://loading.io/spinners/spin/lg.ajax-spinner-gif.gif') center center;
  background-size: cover;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Here is the HTML code for the buttons

```
/* Checkout Button */
<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>

/* Add to basket Button */
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="15" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to basket</button>
```

Or even use Font Awesome, rather than a hosted gif? The slight issue is it needs to be triggered when actually adding to cart other than when it is clicked and perhaps an option isn't filled out.

Comment: Do you submit this form through `<form>` tags, or by some feature like AJAX?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to stop the spinner at the right moment. Since I am not very experienced with WooCommerce, maybe the following solution may help you:

```js
$('.button').on('click', () => {
$('.loading').show();
setTimeout(() => {
 $('.loading').hide();
}, 1000); // Stop the spinner after 1 second
})
```

```css
.loading {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -.5em;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  display: none;
  content: "";
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  animation: none;
  background: url('https://loading.io/spinners/spin/lg.ajax-spinner-gif.gif') center center;
  background-size: cover;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
/* Checkout Button */
<button type="submit" class="button alt test" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>

/* Add to basket Button */
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="15" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to basket</button>

<div class="loading"></div>
```

Comment: It may be a PHP solution needed. As if you press Add to basket and some fields have not been selected it will show the spinner even though it is not submitting. See example here https://demo.themeisle.com/hestia/product/womens-shoulder-handbag-pouch-set/